# How to choose the starting row when computing the reduced row echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having hell of a time going around solving matrices to reduced row echelon form. My main issue is which row to start simplifying values and based on what? I have this example

[image]

so again, the questions are:

1.Which row to start simplifying values?

2.Based on what criteria?

Our professor solved it in the class with no fractions but I could not do it. Even though  I know the 3 operations performed on matrices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where you start is not really a problem.

My tip:

1. Always first make sure you make the first column: 1,0,0
2. Then proceed making the second one: 0,1,0
3. And lastly, 0,0,1

Step one:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&9 \\ 2&-1&1&8 \\ 3&0&-1&3\end{pmatrix}$$

row 3 - 3 times row 1

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&9 \\ 2&-1&1&8 \\ 0&-6&-10&-24\end{pmatrix}$$

row 2 - 2 times row 1

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&9 \\ 0&-5&-5&-10 \\ 0&-6&-10&-24\end{pmatrix}$$

Which simplifies to

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&9 \\ 0&1&1&2 \\ 0&3&5&12\end{pmatrix}$$

Now you can proceed with step 2, and 3.

row 1 - 2 times row 2 and row 3 - 3 times row 2

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1&5 \\ 0&1&1&2 \\ 0&0&2&6\end{pmatrix}$$

Simplifies to

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1&5 \\ 0&1&1&2 \\ 0&0&1&3\end{pmatrix}$$

row 2 - row 3

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1&5 \\ 0&1&0&-1 \\ 0&0&1&3\end{pmatrix}$$

row 1 - row 3

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&2 \\ 0&1&0&-1 \\ 0&0&1&3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Bob..i will try couple of them and see how it goes.

Comment: @P.. You can row reduce, but because of the linear dependency you wont get the identitymatrix.

Comment: @Pirate No problem :)

Comment: Bob , can you please tell me how you simplified matrices in step 3?

Comment: @Pirate I've made an edit to show the separate steps.

Answer (score 4):

The order of steps doesn't matter.  Here are some tips:

1/ If the first row doesn't have 1 as the leading entry, make it be!

2/ Go by columns when you want to make entries becoming 0's.  Usually, start from the first column and make all entries in the first column (except the leading 1 of the first row) be 0's.

3/ Avoid fractions.  They create a big confusion when you apply elementary row/column operations.  Sometimes you can multiply the fractional entries to become whole numbers, apply ERO's or ECO's, then reduce it back to be fraction.  It's a bit redundant, but it helps you see what you have done.

Comment: Hey Cecile..what is ERO's and ECO ?

Comment: @Pirate, Elementary Row Operation and Elementary Column Operation.

Comment: oh ok...thanks Peter.

Comment: @Cecile... I agree with you about avoiding fractions...it becomes messy..anyways..thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can go in whatever order you want - it won't affect the final answer. If you wanted, you could always go about by eliminating the bottom left corner, then the bottom middle, then the middle left, etc. And I really do mean *always*.

At any point, if you get fractions and you don't want fractions, then you could multiply everything by the denominator of the fraction you're getting - that will remove all fractions and just leave integers.

Comment: Thanks man...appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

practice with a 2x3 , look to get 1 or 0 in the first or sec. column . you my have to mul. first.    EXAMP; 2(R1) + R2 ,  ect.  to get started.

Comment: Please, be more careful when you type. Your answer is not so readable.