# How to determine all vectors $b$ for which $Ax = b$ has a solution? Do the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&1&-15&36\\
1&2&-10&41\\
1&2&-9&42
\end{array}\right)$.

Here is the row reduction:
$A = \left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&0&0&51\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1
\end{array}\right)$.

a) Determine all vectors $b$ for which $Ax = b$ has a solution. Write your answer as the span of a set of linearly independent vectors. (I have no idea what this is asking)

b) Do the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$? (How do can you tell?)

I'm lost in class. Please refrain form using rank and im., etc. because I haven't learn those yet. Please show steps and explanations, not only answers, so that I can learn. Thank you

Comment: You need more help than we can give here (we can give answers, but you need much more than that). Make an appointment to see your teacher, to ask what you can do to catch up. Do they have any kind of tutoring services where you are?

Comment: In addition to seeing your instructor, you need to read your text and notes: you're going to need to understand when a set of vectors spans a space, what it means for vectors to be linearly independent. Those are fundamental concepts/definitions, and you need to learn them and work with them as "second nature".

Comment: Unfortunately no... could you please at least give brief explanations with the answers? I really need to learn how to solve these. These are the only questions I don't get after looking through all the notes and text.

Comment: Manny, just giving answers won't help you learn, and we're not in a position to give full lessons.

Comment: ...with answers at least I can try to work them and see if I am on the right path. I don't mean to be rude, but you are not being a help at all. You suggesting me things I have already tried and came here as my last resort...

Comment: @Manny It would do you well here to remember that people are _volunteering_ their time.

Comment: ..yes I understand and that's why I said thanks in advance. But they are turning people away from helping me out...

Comment: Manny-turned-Walter: Is the matrix an augmented matrix? That is, is A a $3\times 3$ matrix augmented with the vector b? Or is a as you've written, a $3 \times 4$ matrix? Whatever the case, please edit your post to include those details. Have you tried row reduction? You've got to dig in and get your "hands dirty".

Comment: Yes, I've tried row reduction but I'm not sure what the question is actually asking. I assume that is the augmented matrix, otherwise we can't solve the questions, correct? That's exactly how the exercise question was given.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324798/reduced-row-echelon-form-any-tips/324807#324807

Here I posted a full answer explaining row reduction. Try for yourself, follow the steps. (In the answers below)

Comment: Hi Bob. Thanks for the suggestion, but I already know how to do row reduction. I just need someone to explain how to find the answers and what the questions are asking.

Comment: Could you please show your row reduction? edit the post to include the row reduced matrix. You need that to answer your questions. And is the question find all vectors $x$ for which $Ax = b$ is a solution? Since $b$ seems to be the vector to the right of the matrix: given?

Comment: Indeed if it is an augmented matrix as you have shown wouldn't $b$ already be given so I think they mean find all solutions $x$.

Comment: This is what's confusing... this was exactly the questions given to me to solve... Ok I've included the row reduction. The second row is inconsistent...

Comment: @amWhy Would the question would not make if it is asking to determine all vectors b for which Ax=b has a solution?

Comment: If that A matrix is not an augmented matrix, there is no way I can solve the questions, correct?

Comment: Walter, if $A$ really is that augmented matrix, then $Ax$ doesn't even make sense.

Comment: You really, really, really need to sit down with someone and go through this stuff. That's what your teacher is paid to do, so, go!

Comment: ....Why doesn't it make sense.... you couldn't at least give a sentence explaining why it doesn't make sense...

Comment: It doesn't make sense because an augmented matrix isn't a matrix. It is just a way to represent two matrices that we perform operations on at the same time for convenience, if I am not mistaken. Someone feel free to correct me it has been a little bit since I took linear algebra and I should know it better.

Comment: Hence if I am correct it wouldn't make sense to talk about an augmented matrix multiplying a matrix. It would make sense to talk about a matrix multiplying a matrix, assuming the first is an $m \times n$ matrix and the second is $n \times p$.

Comment: Ok then... take it not as an augmented matrix... would I still be able to solve the questions though? Or is there an error in the questions? Because I typed them out just like how they were given to me.

Comment: Actually, Walter, you typed it out as "A = ([1,1,1],[1,2,2],[-15,-10,-9], [36, 41, 42])" and then someone edited it into an augmented matrix. And you may not want to hear it, but it's the best advice you are going to get: when you are lost in class, SEE THE TEACHER!